# MySQL Search and replace entire fields not part of it

Tags: mysql, search, replace, phpmyadmin

I want to replace an entire MySQL field in a wordpress database. I want to replace 'Mark' with 'Tom' in custom field 'employee'

i have the following working query:

```
UPDATE 'wp_postmeta' 
SET 'meta_value' = replace(meta_value, 'Mark', 'Tom') 
WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE 'employee'
```

The problem i am having is that i dont want to replace 'Mark' in 'Mark Frey' (->Tom Frey) or 'Markus' (->Tomus).
I only want to replace the entire field, and not part of it. The results should look like:

Mark -> Tom

Mark Frey -> Mark Frey

Markus -> Markus

Is it possible to do this in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a condition to the `WHERE` clause which checks that the `meta_value` field precisely equals what you want to replace, in this case `'Mark'`:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'Mark', 'Tom') 
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'employee' AND
      meta_value = 'Mark'
```

Note that I removed the single quotes which you had the table and field names, because they don't belong there, at least not in a raw MySQL query.

**Update:**

As @HankyPanky pointed out, you could also just do a direct update of the `meta_value`:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = 'Tom'
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'employee' AND
      meta_value = 'Mark'
```

Comment: If exact `meta_value` is known, can't we remove the `REPLACE` call altogether and use a simple assignment.  `SET meta_value='Tom'`

Comment: @HankyPanky It helps to think about the question first :-)

Comment: i tried the second solution (without REPLACE) and it worked.